# iOS UIWebView with YouTube video does not dismiss when done button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that links to a youtube video. When I press to watch the video, it enters full screen mode, but when I press the "DONE" button in the top left corner, then the video leaves fullscreen but then instantly re-enters full screen. I found that if I pause the video before I press "DONE" then it works as expected. Has anyone else run into this problem?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let url = URL.init(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/we8o1WPx_c0")
        let urlrequest = URLRequest.init(url: url!)
        videoWebView.loadRequest(urlrequest)
    }
```

Here's a video of what's happening if it's not clear from my description: https://youtu.be/qSC6VdPANGg

Comment: have you implemented web view delegates too ?

Comment: I have tried it both ways. Same issue.

Comment: Hey in order to debug it, I would suggest you to put your breakpoints on `viewdidload` and other method of life cycle, as well as from the places where you are loading the webview, to see where the control reaches when you press done button in both the scenarios.
It should give more details to proceed further.

Comment: Control doesn't change when hitting the done button. Neither `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` are called when dismissing the video.

Comment: Ok I'll try to replicate the same and get back to you

Comment: Your webview is in full screen or has some fixed height? Also are you on iOS 9 or 10 and did you try to use wkwebview?

Comment: I have not tried WKWebView. I am using iOS 10.

Comment: I tried, this but it works as expected for me both on iOS simulator and iPhone 7

Comment: I tested it on a friend's device and got the problem.

Comment: Weird issue..glad to know WKWebView is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView has been deprecated. I swapped UIWebView for WKWebView and everything works as expected.

After putting a UIView on the storyboard named `videoContainer` I have this:

```
self.videoWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.videoContainer.bounds)
let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/we8o1WPx_c0")
videoWebView!.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
self.videoContainer.addSubview(videoWebView!)
```